# How to log top level json instead of into message with LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder?

Tags: logstash-logback-encoder

So using LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder I can do stuff like:

```
        <pattern>
          <pattern>{ "fieldName": "#tryJson{%message}" }</pattern>
        </pattern>
```

Generates `{ fieldName: [NESTEDJSONHERE] }`

But how can I just generate a json at the top level instead of nested one level deep?
e.g.:

```
        <pattern>
          <pattern>{ #tryJson{%message} }</pattern>
        </pattern>
```

generating
`{ [JSONHERE] }`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, seems this is not supported